# Opportunity stages required Contact roles other than the first stage

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

I have a use case whenever I change the opportunity stage from Stage - 1 to any other stage Contact role should be mandatory to change the stage other wise it has to throw a error message how can I achieve this using validation rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this via Validation Rule unless you have a field on Opportunity that allows you to know if there are Contact Roles associated.

As a suggestion you may take a look into the [addError() sObject method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) and try to implement this using a trigger.